# How to keep a light's reflection only

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

Using eevee , it is possible to set a light and disable all of it effects beside the light's reflection on the mesh , i just want to keep the shinny parts ( for some lights , not all )

I think it's called the specular or something

Comment: With the light selected, look on properties/object data/light.  Set the volume and diffuse sliders to 0 (leaving specular at 1.)  Is that what you want?

Comment: I do not have any of these settings  ( volume / diffuse )